# How can I check if a signed integer is positive?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Using bitwise operators and I suppose addition and subtraction, how can I check if a signed integer is positive (specifically, not negative and not zero)? I'm sure the answer to this is very simple, but it's just not coming to me.

Comment: Just a thought - the answers below are good, but I think that you shouldn't use these in practice because on a modern CPU, a comparison like "> 0" is just 1 instruction, and any of the below answers are going to be multiple instructions, possibly not making use of separate pipelines or cores.  They're useful if you are making your own circuit for special comparison and need to reduce logic path delay.

Comment: This might be a homework question specifically limiting the use of such comparisons :)

Comment: it's related to a larger homework problem, this is just one part that i can't get a grasp of

Comment: Please don't forget to add the `homework` tag so people who avoid homework questions can avoid such questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want an "is strictly positive" predicate for `int n` without using conditionals (assuming 2's complement):

- `-n` will have the sign (top) bit set if `n` was strictly positive, and clear in all other cases *except* `n == INT_MIN`;
- `~n` will have the sign bit set if `n` was strictly positive, or 0, and clear in all other cases *including* `n == INT_MIN`;
- ...so `-n & ~n` will have the sign bit set if n was strictly positive, and clear in all other cases.

Apply an *unsigned* shift to turn this into a 0 / 1 answer:

```
int strictly_positive = (unsigned)(-n & ~n) >> ((sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
```

EDIT: as caf points out in the comments, `-n` causes an overflow when `n == INT_MIN` (still assuming 2's complement).  The C standard allows the program to fail in this case (for example, you can enable traps for signed overflow using GCC with the`-ftrapv` option).  Casting `n` to unsigned fixes the problem (unsigned arithmetic does not cause overflows).  So an improvement would be:

```
unsigned u = (unsigned)n;
int strictly_positive = (-u & ~u) >> ((sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
```

Comment: `-n` may overflow in the case of `n == INT_MIN`.

Comment: Strictly, that only works on 2's complement arithmetic (which are, I grant you, the practically significant systems).  With a negative zero (1's complement or sign-magnitude), your assertions are not valid.

Comment: @Jonathan: if you cast to `unsigned` before applying the `~` operator, then it works for all systems.

Comment: @caf: Updated, thanks (forgot that signed overflow can trap).

Comment: Now it just has the problem in the (admittedly, very theoretical) "`int` has as many value bits as `unsigned int`" case ;)

Comment: @caf: And the problem that `sizeof` is not the right thing to compute the width of a type... there may be padding bits. See my comment to Jonathan's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check the most significant bit. 0 is positive, 1 is negative.

Comment: This fails for zero, which is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: But if the most significant bit is 0 and all the other bits are zero, it returns 'positive' but zero is supposed to be excluded.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use the obvious comparison operators, then you have to work harder:

```
int i = anyValue;
if (i && !(i & (1U << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1))))
    /* I'm almost positive it is positive */
```

The first term checks that the value is not zero; the second checks that the value does not have the leading bit set.  That should work for 2's-complement, 1's-complement or sign-magnitude integers.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has undefined behaviour ;)  - 2 raised to the power of `(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)` is certainly not representable in `int`.

Comment: @caf: that can be addressed by converting the 1 that is shifted to `unsigned int` with a U suffix...which means that `i` will be converted to `unsigned int` too.  Bit-shifting should normally be done on unsigned quantities anyway.

Comment: Yep, that fixes the UB - now you just have to worry about the (even more theoretical!) case where `int` and `unsigned int` have the same number of value bits...

Comment: @caf: I don't think the standard allows that.

Comment: @R: It does, unfortunately - in 6.2.6.2: "if there are
M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M <= N" - implying that you could have (for example) `int` with range -131072 to 131071 and `unsigned int` with range 0 to 131071.

Comment: @caf: did you mean 'where `int` and `unsigned int` have _different_ numbers of bits'?  I don't think that's a problem because I think the standard requires them to have the same number of bits.

Comment: @Jonathan: No, the problem is when they have an equal number of *value* bits (typically, the unsigned type has one more value bit than the corresponding signed type).  When this is the case, your shift of `1U` may end up with 0 as the result; and also the "usual arithmetic conversion" of `i` to `unsigned` will map negative and positive values onto the same range of values in the `unsigned` type.

Comment: Generally a shift with a calculation using `sizeof` will not always work since the width of a type and its size are not forcebly related in that way. There may be padding bits. I think an expression like `(((unsigned)-1u)/2u)+1u)` would be more portable. Though this also supposes that `signed` and `unsigned` have the same width.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how the signedness is represented. Often it's done with *two's-complement* or with a simple *sign bit* - I think both of these could be checked with a simple logical and.

Answer (score 0):

Check that is not 0 and the most significant bit is 0, something like:

```
int positive(int x) {
   return x && (x & 0x80000000);
}
```

Comment: What about return x && (x & MIN_INT) ?